# Golang: Channels - fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

Tags: goroutine, channel

OS: Win11
Lang: Golang
Typic: goroutine & channels

**My goal:** I am writing some string into inputStream. I try to delete all duplicates from the string and after to write one symbol after another into outputStream.
At the end I want to read outputStream and I want to see my initial string without duplicates.

The next step, I will try to read my outputStream to see if all values are properly written there from inputStream

**issue:**
When I am executing my code below, I am getting fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

func addvaluesInputStream(inputStream chan string, str string) {
   for v := range str {
      l := string(str[v])
      inputStream <- l
   }
   close(inputStream)
}

func removeDuplicates(inputStream, outputStream chan string) {

   var tmp string

   for i := range inputStream {
      if tmp != i {
         outputStream <- i
         tmp = i
      }
   }
   close(outputStream)
}

func main() {

   inputStream := make(chan string)
   outputStream := make(chan string)
   fmt.Println("Step 1")
   str := "8qqqqq1q12334Qtx"

   go addvaluesInputStream(inputStream, str)

   removeDuplicates(inputStream, outputStream)

}
```

As soon as I understand why I am getting this error, I will add something like that to read my outputStream:

```
    for n := range outputStream {
        //fmt.Println(n)
        fmt.Printf("%v", n)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The dead lock you are getting  because in `removeDuplicates` you are sending a value to `outputStream` channel, but there is no receiver is ready to receive the data from that channel.

see https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#channels

https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2

> By default, sends and receives block until the other side is ready. This allows goroutines to synchronize without explicit locks or condition variables.

run **removeDuplicates** as concurrently and read the data from the channel as well, then the issue will be resolved.

```
go addvaluesInputStream(inputStream, str)
go removeDuplicates(inputStream, outputStream)

for n := range outputStream {
    //fmt.Println(n)
    fmt.Printf("%v", n)
}
```